# Computation of relation between angular power spectrum and matter power spectrum

Tags: cosmology, astrophysics, fourier-transform

How to write the 3D power spectrum, $\mathrm{P}(\mathrm{k})$, as an integral of the angular power spectrum, $\mathrm{C_\ell}$ ?

I have the following equation,
$$
C_{\ell}\left(z, z^{\prime}\right)=\int_{0}^{\infty} d k k^{2} j_{\ell}(k z) j_{\ell}\left(k z^{\prime}\right) P(k)
$$
where $j_{\ell}$ are the spherical Bessel functions.

I would like to invert this relation and write $\mathrm{P}(\mathrm{k})$ as a function of $\mathrm{C_\ell}$.

I don't know if this is a well known result, but I couldn't find anything.

Any ideas on how to tackle this problem

PS : maybe this post deserves to be placed in astrophysics exchange forum. Don't hesitate to move it on the appropriate forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given
$$ \tag{1}
C_{\ell}\left(z, z^{\prime}\right)=\int_{0}^{\infty} d k k^{2} j_{\ell}(k z) j_{\ell}\left(k z^{\prime}\right) P(k)
$$
Question: how to invert the integral to find the function $P(k)$?

---

The closure relation for spherical Bessel function:
$$ \tag{2}
\int_0^\infty x^2 j_n(xu) j_n(xv) dx = \frac{\pi}{2u^2} \delta(u-v).
$$

Multipy Eq.(1) with $z^2 j_\ell(qz)$ and integral over $z$:
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty z^2 j_\ell(qz) C_{\ell}\left(z, z^{\prime}\right) dz =&\int_{0}^{\infty} d k k^{2} \left\{ \int^0_\infty z^2 dz j_\ell(qz) j_{\ell}(k z)\right\} j_{\ell}\left(k z^{\prime}\right) P(k) \\
=&\int_{0}^{\infty} d k k^{2} \left\{\frac{\pi}{2q^2} \delta(q-k)\right\} j_{\ell}\left(k z^{\prime}\right) P(k) \\
=& q^{2} \frac{\pi}{2q^2} j_{\ell}\left(q z^{\prime}\right) P(q) \tag{3}.
\end{align}

Once again multiply Eq.(3) with $z'^2 j_\ell(q'z')$ and integral over $z'$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty z'^2 dz' j_\ell(q'z') \int_0^\infty z^2 j_\ell(qz) C_{\ell}\left(z, z^{\prime}\right) dz 
=&  \frac{\pi}{2} \left\{\int_0^\infty z'^2 dz' j_\ell(q'z') j_{\ell}(q z') \right\} P(q).\\
=&  \frac{\pi}{2} \left\{ \frac{\pi}{2q'^2} \delta(q-q') \right\} P(q) \tag{4}.\\
\end{align}

To move the $\delta$ function in the right-hand-side, we multiply Eq. (4) (note that only $q=q'$ has contribution) with $q'^2$ and integral over $q'$:
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty dq' q'^2\int_0^\infty z'^2 dz' j_\ell(q'z') \int_0^\infty z^2 j_\ell(q'z) C_{\ell}\left(z, z'\right) dz 
=& \frac{\pi^2}{4} \int_0^\infty  dq' \delta(q-q')  P(q).\\
=& \frac{\pi^2}{4}  P(q) \tag{5}.
\end{align}

The left-hand-side of Eq.(5);
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty dq' & q'^2\int_0^\infty z'^2 dz' j_\ell(q'z') \int_0^\infty z^2 j_\ell(q'z) C_{\ell}\left(z, z'\right) dz \\
= &  \int_0^\infty z'^2 dz' \int_0^\infty z^2 dz \left\{ \int_0^\infty dq' q'^2 j_\ell(q'z')  j_\ell(q'z) \right\} C_{\ell}(z, z') \\
= &  \int_0^\infty z'^2 dz' \int_0^\infty z^2 dz \left\{  \frac{\pi}{2z^2} \delta(z-z') \right\} C_{\ell}(z, z') \\
= & \frac{\pi}{2} \int_0^\infty z^2 dz  C_{\ell}(z, z). \tag{6}
\end{align}

Combine Eq.(5) and Eq.(6)
$$
  P(q) = \frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^\infty z^2 dz  C_{\ell}(z, z) = P_0.
$$

$P(k)$ is a constant independent of $k$. This renders Eq.(1) to be:
\begin{align*}
C_{\ell}\left(z, z^{\prime}\right) &=\int_{0}^{\infty} d k k^{2} j_{\ell}(k z) j_{\ell}\left(k z^{\prime}\right) P(k);\\
&= P_0 \int_{0}^{\infty} d k k^{2} j_{\ell}(k z) j_{\ell}\left(k z^{\prime}\right)\\
&= \frac{\pi P_0}{2 z^2} \delta \left( z- z'\right).
\end{align*}

It means that if a two-variable function $C_\ell(z. z')$ can be bessel-fourier transformed with a single $k$, then $C_\ell(z, z')$ is a delta-function $\delta(z-z')$.

Comment: ytlu. what a beautiful demonstration (I am only a student) ! That would mean that we can pass from 3D to 2D and inversely ? and what does represent the variable $q$ : is it related to $k$ wave number ? Thanks a lot for your help, Regards

Comment: Yes. $k$ or $q$ is a dummy index. You may replace $q$ by $k$ in the end.

Comment: ok, it is kind from your part.

Comment: just a question : $C_{\ell}$ has no dependence in $k$ scale ? only angular dependent and redshift dependent ? since only redshift $z$ appears in your expression ?

Comment: That bothers me either. But since I don't understand the physics of your equation, I have no clues at all. I just did it as a math problem.

Comment: ok, so just to give some clues : in cosmology, the angular power spectrum depends on multipole noted $l$ (Legendre transformation) which is related to angular quantities ($\theta$ and $\phi$). But the matter power spectrum is dependent of $k$ wave number (with Fourier transform). I think I am wrong by saying that, in definition of $C_{\ell}$, one writes $C_{\ell}\left(z, z^{\prime}\right)$ where $z$ and $z'$ could be understood like redshift. What do $z$ and $z'$ represent from your point of view in the expression $C_{\ell}\left(z, z^{\prime}\right)$ ?

Comment: is it really linked to multipole $l$ and with which way ? Best regards

Comment: Hello, I really need to know what does $z$ and $z'$ represent in the equation : $P(k) = \frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^\infty z^2 dz  C_{\ell}(z, z).$. Does $z$ represent a redshift, or rather the inverse of $k$ scale, i.e the dimension of a length like radial coordinates $r$ ? Moreover, why doesn't $k$ appear in this formula ? Regards

Comment: I added some text to explain why the $P(k)$ is a constant independent of $k$. It is rooted in the Bessel's transform of two variables $z$ and $z'$ by a single $k$ factor. I guess that $z$ is redshift, a scale of the universe radius $R(z)$.